# Why i get hashed .jpeg file when running 'npm run build' with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack

Im a new beginner on develop react app.
Im trying to figure out how to set up my webpack.config.js file.

I have following ended up with this structure as you can see on the picture link below.

[image: This is how my client folder looks like]

My question is: When im running 'npm run build' , its hashing the picture and put it into the /dist folder. How can i configure so it does not?

Because im using copyWebpackPlugin() to copy my images and push it to the dist folder, but i dont want the picture which i marked with arrow.

If anyone have some advice just bring it on.

This is how my webpack.config.js file look like:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const CleanWebpackPlugin = require("clean-webpack-plugin");
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require("copy-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  mode: "development",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loader: "babel-loader"
      },
      {
        test: /\.s?css$/,
        loader: ["style-loader", "css-loader"]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)(\?[a-z0-9=.]+)?$/,
        loader: "url-loader?limit=100000"
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: { extensions: [".js", ".jsx"] },
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/"),
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  devtool: "cheap-module-eval-source-map",
  devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, "public/"),
    proxy: {
      "/api/*": {
        target: "http://localhost:3000/",
        secure: "true"
      }
    },
    port: 4000,
    publicPath: "http://localhost:4000/dist/",
    hotOnly: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(["dist"]),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: "index.html",
      template: "./public/index.html"
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: "public/images", to: "images" }])
  ]
};
```

Comment: Why exactly you don't want hash on your images?

Comment: When i load my app it dosent show the picture :/ i have added it in my /styles/App.css , im importing the CSS in 'index.js' . This is what i added in App.css -> background: url('/images/developer.jpeg') no-repeat; . But with the solution where im copying over with CopyWebpackHtmlPlugin, im just copied over the images then it works. Maybe im doing something wrong ?

Comment: what if you try: `url('relative/path/to/images/developer.jpeg')`?

Comment: Sorry but im not sure what u mean when u say relative/path/to ? u mean? 'src/images/developer.jpg' ?

Comment: relative path. The relative path from where you are to where the image is.

Comment: I changed to -> background: url('../../public/images/developer.jpeg') no-repeat; i get this error -> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) , its trying to fetch from http://localhost:4000/5fedc415e22274030222a296c98ad1f5.jpeg

Comment: Try moving your `images` folder into your `src`, so that way you won't have to traverse out of it (boilerplates, like C.R.A, restrict imports to src only -- for security reasons). In addition, the `relative path` will be the path required from the `.scss` file to the `images` folder location. So if your stylesheet was housed inside `styles`, then it would be `background: url('../images/developer.jpeg') no-repeat;` or "out of styles, into images, to developer.jpeg". Also, don't use `url-loader`, it's extremely resource intensive. Use `file-loader`. See JameelM's answer for webpack setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest instead of **copy-webpack-plugin** use **file-loader** to copy images

```
 {
                test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|jpeg)$/,
                use: [{
                    loader: 'file-loader',
                    options: {
                        name: 'images/[name].[ext]',
                    }
                }]
            }
```

if you  want **hash** instead of name

```
name: 'images/[hash].[ext]',
```

*Package*

> npm install --save-dev file-loader

Comment: I tried this options, still failed with this message -> GET http://localhost:4000/images/developer.jpeg 404 (Not Found) . in webpack i removed url-loader and used the code u gave me. In App.css i changes to background: url('../images/developer.jpeg') no-repeat; , and in App.js i have imported the picture -> import '../images/developer.jpeg'; . and i also moved images folder to /src folder

Comment: @mac123 Absolutely agree with this answer, but your question was „why?” My answer explained it.

Answer (score 0):

It is because the `url-loader` has a [default fallback](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/#fallback) to `file-loader`. So if your image is bigger than the limit you have set for `url-loader`, it does not rewrite the image to base64 data:image in your css, instead gives it to `file-loader` and it copies that image to your dist folder (output path).

So if you do not want this, disable the fallback option for `url-loader`

But I also think you should have configure your webpack to copy the files with `file-loader` properly instead that copy plugin. But you know...

*I would give you an example based on your config but I am currently on mobile so I can't code right now.*